# How can I explain to my professor his argument invokes the AC?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

This is not the standard definition, but my topology professor restricted contexts in metric spaces.

> Definition
>
> An open set $U$ in a metric space $X$ is a subset of $X$ such that the interior of it and $U$ Itself are identical. (Interior point $x$ of a subset $A$ is a point of which there exists a ball containing $x$, contained in $A$.

With this definition, He showed that "Every open set in a metric space is a union of balls."

Below is his argument:

> Assume that $U$ is open.
>
> Let $x\in U$.
>
> Then, by definition, there exists $r(x)$ such that $B(x,r(x))\subset U$, so that $U=\bigcup_{x\in U} B(x,r(x))$.

I'm not asking that this can be resolved easily without Axiom of Choice, but I'm asking how do I explain this to my professor his argument invokes Axiom of Choice. I told him that *choosing $r(x)$ for each $x$ is a consequence of the axiom of choice*, but he does not seem to understand me. Please help.

Comment: No. By definition a choice function exists, isn't it? But, I am no expert on set theory.

Comment: @Aryabhata Yes, it's exactly the definition of "AC", i find it hard to explain him that the argument he used is exactly by the definition of "AC", since he asked me back *how*?

Comment: I meant that the definition already provides you a choice function. So there is no invocation of AC going on.

Comment: @Aryabhata I'm afraid to say that you are wrong. Definition only asserts "existence of such $r$ for each $x$. When you want to choose each for each $x$ and to take union of those, you *have to choose*

Comment: I might well be, no argument about that. The definition talks about existence of _a_ ball (rather than a set of balls), you take that ball, and take its radius. I might be implicitly invoking AC here, and is one reason I gladly accept AC :-) Looking forward to the answers here, thanks for asking this.

Comment: Remember that there is no hurry in working this out with your professor. Don't be annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion is not to bother your professor with this very much.

There are theorems whose choiceless proofs are very different than their choice-using proofs. There are theorems whose usual proof can be easily modified by showing that the arbitrary choice has some easy canonical choice instead.

When it is the former case, I agree that it might be worth insisting that a particular proof is using, or not using, the axiom of choice. But in the latter case it usually amount to unnecessary nitpicking (and that can always get people to dislike you).

In principle, you are right. When we say "*some $r(x)$*" rather than "The least $n$ such that ..." then we secretly invoke the axiom of choice. However since we can prove that the axiom of choice *for this family of sets* is true, there's little harm in this. (Not to mention that a lot of the time people use the axiom of choice in so many other places without noticing, that this one place where it's not a big deal shouldn't be different too.)

Comment: I disagree that we are invoking choice. We may just not bother to be explicit about the choice function because it is trivial in this case.

Comment: Andres, if the choice function is so trivial, can you tell us what it is? I agree with Asaf and John that the professor's proof uses choice. It didn't have to, but it does.

Comment: @SteveKass Of course I can. You can have $r(x)$ be the positive rational with least index in some fixed enumeration such that $B(x,r(x))\subseteq U$. Your answer exhibits a different valid choice. Etc. Proofs are not formal arguments that computers check, we leave minor details out all the time. Does not mean we forgot to verify those details, or are using hidden additional assumptions.

Comment: @Steve: I didn't really say that the proof is using the axiom of choice. I said that it seems as if it is using it, but in fact since we can prove the existence of a choice function for the particular family considered here, it's not a big deal.

Comment: For an argument with a much more subtle choice function, consider Neugebauer theorem: A function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is a derivative iff for each closed interval $I$ there is an $x_I$ in the interior of $I$ such that $\lim_{I\to x}f(x_I)=f(x)$ for all $x$, and $f(x_I)\mathrm{lh}(I)=f(x_J)\mathrm{lh}(J)+f(x_K)\mathrm{lh}(K)$ whenever $I,L,K$ are closed intervals, $I=J\cup K$, and the interiors of $J$ and $K$ are disjoint. (Cont.)

Comment: I agree it's not a big deal to write a proof this way, but the discussion is a nice example of how to analyze a proof. Maybe we can agree on this: The proof omits any justification that such an $r(x)$ exists. There are two straightforward ways to supply one: a) Appeal to the axiom of choice. B) Give an explicit construction of $r(x)$ for each $x$. The professor supplied neither, so even though the appeal to choice is the shorter argument, it's probably wrong to say the professor "used" choice. The professor used nothing to justify $r(x)$ exists, but in a proof like this that's not a problem.

Comment: (Cont.) Here, $\mathrm{lh}(I)$ is the length of $I$, and $\lim_{I\to x}\phi(I)=t$ iff for all $\epsilon>0$ there is $\delta>0$ such that whenever $I$ is an interval with $\mathrm{lh}(I)<\delta$ and $x$ is in the interior of $I$, then $|\phi(I)-t|<\epsilon$. Suppose, for example, that $f$ is a derivative. An obvious choice of $x_I$ is a point such that if $I=[a,b]$, and $f=F'$, then $(F(b)-F(a))/(b-a)=f(x_I)$. Such a point exists by the mean value theorem. On the face of it, this is a blatant use of choice (there may be many points $c$ with $(F(b)-F(a))/(b-a)=F'(c)$). (Cont.)

Comment: (Cont.) But whether choice is really used here is not an issue of whether Neugebauer bothered to write down a choice function or not. It is instead a genuine question in descriptive set theory related to what we call analytic uniformization. If one is going to make a point about whether choice is used or not in a proof, this theorem is a much more interesting example.

Comment: (And yet again, not an ideal example, as the theorem can be restated in a way that avoids having to make the choice.)

Comment: @SteveKass: I would say the choice is given by the definition. The definition guarantees existence of a $B_x$ for every point $x$. Your choice function is $r(B_x)$, $r$ being the radius function. I was hoping the answers would address what defining statements like: "For every x, there is a Ball" really mean. Do they imply existence of a choice function? etc.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Given a structure of a metric space, there is a uniform formula which takes as parameters a point and a radius and returns a set; the statement in the question is that given an open set in a metric space, every point has an open ball contained in the open set; since the points are given we need to "choose a radius" to witness that. But there are many radii to choose from; what I wrote in my answer, and what Andres points out, is that the axiom of choice is not really used, because we can write down a choice function that chooses a suitable radius for each point. [...]

Comment: [...] So even if we don't write the details explicitly this isn't really an appeal to the axiom of choice. But rather "leaving the details to the reader to verify". (Arguably, I'm not making this point very clearly, whereas Andres is flat out saying that.)

Comment: Asaf, as I said above, what's clear is that the professor didn't write "the details" explicitly. But to say he "used AC" is a reach, especially since AC isn't needed (in fact it's true for this collection of sets). If in some proof where $a$ was a real number, I wrote "Let $x$ be strictly between $a$ and $a+1$, I'm certainly leaving out some justification, but beyond "a justification that such an $x$ exists," who's to say exactly what I left out. Should I have said 1≠0? Should I have mentioned the completeness of the reals? Should I have defined $x$ constructively as $x+1/2$?

Comment: @Steve: Choosing **one** number between $a$ and $a+1$ never required the axiom of choice. At all. If $U$ is an infinite open set, then we have to make infinitely many choices. As luck would have it, we can do them at once, but it might have well be a situation where we can't -- and then the axiom of choice is needed. I don't fully understand the point you're trying to make in that comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I was trying to talk about was a statement like this: "...space, _every_ point has _an_ open ball in the open set...". What does this even mean? There is a function from set of points to set of open balls? or something else? Assuming radius of an open ball is well defined, we can just compose the two. Why do we even have a choice of multiple radii? The definition only talks about the existence of _a_ ball. I probably misunderstood the point you are trying to make, though.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I see. This means that there is a function mapping each point in the open set to an open ball which is a subset of the fixed open set. However, as I said, open balls are uniquely determined by their center and radius, and so we can assume without loss of generality that for each point, the ball is centered around it. So we essentially reduce into choose radii. Why do we have a choice of many radii? Well, not always of course (think of an open singleton), but in a connected nontrivial metric space (for example) if $r_1<r_2$ and $r_2$ is a suitable radius, then so must be $r_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Right, I missed the fact that the proof is talking about $B(x, r(x))$ (i.e. a ball centered at $x$, which the definition does not provide). That does need a proof. But I believe OP was claiming that the AC is used in choosing such a ball for every $x$, i.e. even if the definition were changed to "there is a ball centered at $x$...", I believe he would still have that objection. Sorry, should have read things more carefully. Thanks for taking the time to explain it.

Comment: @Asaf: The point I'm making is that we always leave some details out. It's not always worth worrying about the fact that there might be some setting different from the one we have that would require some powerful theorem that our setting could simply use in lieu of other tools, such as a straightforward construction.

Comment: @Aryabhata: Yes, the claim is that there is such ball; but in particular there is such ball centered around $x$. And again, as I keep saying, the fact that there are plenty of choices doesn't mean that we can't prove that there is a canonical one. There are continuum many choice functions from the set of finite, non-empty subsets of $\Bbb N$. This doesn't mean we can't just pick the least element in each set.

Comment: @Steve: I still don't understand what you're fussing about here. From one end it seems that you're bothered that I wrote that this "looks as if we appeal to the axiom of choice", but on the other hand it seems that you are saying "Oh, we leave so many details out, it's not a big deal here... let it be." and those two approaches, together, seem to me as oxymoron. So which one is it?

Answer (score 4):

Setting aside the question of whether his argument uses the axiom of choice, the result doesn’t depend on it, and the proof is basically the same. Define $r(x)=\frac{1}{n}$, where $n$ is the smallest positive integer for which $B(x,\frac{1}{n})\subseteq U$.

Comment: As i said in my post,i know that it can be *easily resolved*. I'm asking how to explain that argument itself uses AC..

Comment: I exactly see what the defference of the argument my prof used and you used is. I'm asking how to explain such difference

Comment: I’m not convinced his argument does use AC, but I’m not a logician. I assume you would not object if he took $U=\displaystyle\bigcup_{\substack{x\in U,r\in\mathbb{R}\\B(x,r)\subseteq U}} B(x,r)$?

Comment: Exactly. How do i explain this difference is by AC?

Comment: The difference between the union and the professor's argument is that the union grabs _everything_ so that there is no choice involved. The professor has taken a specific subset of open balls, precisely one ball per point $x$. I agree that seems to involve some form of choice.

Comment: Ok, I see your point now. I can’t second-guess what will get your professor to see it, but the answer to this question might be good to quote: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8204/if-forall-x-exists-y-rx-y-then-is-it-true-that-y-yx

Comment: Rereading your original post, you said "I told him that *choosing $r(x)$ for each $x$ is a consequence of the axiom of choice*, but he does not seem to understand me." It might be better to say something like "How do you know such a *function* $r$ exists? You haven't defined $r(x)$ for each $x$, so - while there is a way to do that in this case that completes the proof - if you don't, you're relying on AC to be able to even talk about this function $r$." It's really tricky to explain (even to us mathematicians), because we're mostly not constructivists, and we generally accept AC.

Comment: The argument does not use choice. It is not that every time we use a choice function we are using the axiom of choice. There is an obvious choice function in this case, so choice is not invoked. That superficially the argument, as presented, appears to use choice, does not mean that it does.

Comment: Andres, what is the "obvious choice function in this case"? If I give you a point $u\in U$, please tell me how to find $r(u)$.

Comment: This strikes me as audience-dependent. A set theorist, paying attention to choice issues and seeing this argument, would reflexively and perhaps unconsciously fill in the missing explicit definition of a particular $r(x)$ and then say that the axiom of choice is not used. A beginning student would not be likely to do that.  Such a student would take the argument at face value, inferring the existence of the function directly from "for each $x$ there exists an $r$ ..." without any particular $r$ being specified; this form of the argument does use the axiom of choice.